# How much current does an LED in optocoupler draw?

Tags: current, relay, opto-isolator, nodemcu

I am planning to actuate the relay (opto-isolated) using the GPIO pins of Nodemcu. NodeMcu's datasheet says that maximum current that can be drawn out of a GPIO pin is 12 mA. Any load more that may damage the device. Is it safe to use this relay -  https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00NR31V3W . How much current does its optocoupler LED draw?

Comment: NodeMCU's pins output 3.3V. This module in Amazon requires 5V (see the first question there). So it won't work.

Comment: Look at all the answers for the question.

Comment: What does the datasheet of the optocopler say?

Comment: Without the exact schematic for that board it cannot be said for sure. But I assume the board contains current limiting resistors to the optocoupler inputs. With 3.3V input, essentially the current thru the LEDs is smaller. So it may or may not be enough to drive the relays reliably, but apparently the people who tested it were lucky.

Comment: The description says 15 to 20 ma per channel needed.

Comment: You are asking a photodiode or phototransistor to turn on the relay. Over temperature.